# Is there a way to create a dynamic type assignment in C

Tags: arrays, c, types

I am working to create a set of functions in C that will allow a dynamically growing array.  In this example I have create a struct with a variable titled `len` that stores the active length of the array, another variable titled `size` that stores the total length of the array assigned during initialization, and another variable titled `array` which is a pointer to the memory containing the array data.  In this example the variable `array` is initialized in the struct as an integer.  Within the function titled `int_array` I initialize the array and and return the struct.  Within that function I call the `init_int_array` function that does the heavy lifting.  In addition, I have another function titled `append_int_array` that checks the memory allocation and assigns another chunk of memory if necessary and then appends the array with a new index/variable.  As you can see, this example is hard coded for an integer, and I will need to repeat these lines of code for every other data type if I want an array to contain that type of data.  There has got to be a way to instantiate the struct so that the variable `array` can be a different data type so that I do not have to repeat all lines of code for every data type, but I am not sure what that method is.  Any help would be appreciated.  The code is shown below. NOTE: I also have a function to free the array memory after use, but I am omitting it since it is not relevant to the question.

array.h

```
#ifndef ARRAY_H
#define ARRAY_H

#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struc
{
    int *array;
    size_t len;
    size_t size;
}Array;

void init_int_array(Array, size_t num_indices);
Array int_array(size_t num_indices);
void append_int_array(Array *array, int item);

#endif /* ARRAY_H */
```

Array.c

```
void init_int_array(Array *array, size_t num_indices) {
    /* This function initializes the array with a guess for
       the total array size (i.e. num_indices)
     */
    int *int_pointer;

    int_pointer = (int *)malloc(num_indices * sizeof(int));

    if (int_pointer == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to allocate memory, exiting.\n");
        free(int_pointer);
        exit(0);
    }
    else {
        array->array = int_pointer;
        array->len = 0;
        array->size = num_indices;
    }
}

Array int_array(size_t num_indices) {
    /* This function calls init_int_array to initialize
       the array and returns a struct containing the array
     */
    Array array;
    init_int_array(&array, num_indices);
    return array;
}

void append_int_array(Array *array, int item) {
    /* This function adds a data point/index to the array
       and also doubles the memory allocation if necessary
       to incorporate the new data point.
     */
    array->len++;
    if (array->len == array->size){
        array->size *= 2;
        int *int_pointer;
        int_pointer = (int *)realloc(array->array, array->size * sizeof(int));

        if (int_pointer == NULL) {
            printf("Unable to reallocate memory, exiting.\n");
            free(int_pointer);
            exit(0);
        }
        else {
            array->array = int_pointer;
            array->array[array->len - 1] = item;
        }
    }
    else
    array->array[array->len - 1] = item;
}
```

Comment: You can use a preprocessor macro with the type as a macro argument

Comment: People use code generators and C++ templates for this sort of thing usually

Comment: Unrelated to the question, you might want to check out _flexible array members_.

Comment: A much simpler solution would be to use a void pointer and store the element size. Qsort and bsearch are examples of how to handle this

Comment: Your first snippet had a typo

Comment: You could also do this with `_Generic` but that probably comes with something like X macros as well. Much safer and more maintainable than void pointers, but also much harder to read.

Comment: "Is there a way to create a dynamic type assignment" --> Some.  `int n = rand() % 10 + 1; char p[n];` ---> The type of `p` is dynamically determined at run time.

Comment: "this example is hard coded for an integer" --> better as "this example is hard coded for an `int`".  _integer_ is not synonymous with `int`.

Comment: Jon, One step toward removing _type_ in code: `int_pointer = (int *)malloc(num_indices * sizeof(int));` --> `int_pointer = malloc(num_indices * sizeof int_pointer[0]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is rewrite your header like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    void *array; // buffer
    size_t len;  // amount used
    size_t elem; // size of element
    size_t size; // size of buffer
} Array;

void init_array(Array *, size_t num_indices, size_t elem);
Array array(size_t num_indices, size_t elem);
void append_array(Array *array, void *item);
```

The changes to your code would be as follows:

1. Remove references to `int` in the name.
2. Make all inputs be to arbitrary type using `void *`.
3. Use `array.elem` instead of `sizeof(int)`.
4. The biggest change is that elements to append will be passed by pointer, not by value.
5. Cast the buffer to whatever type you need to access elements.
6. Cast the buffer to `char *` internally to do pointer math on it.

Here is a sample calling sequence you could use:

```
Array buf = array(10, sizeof(int));
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    append_array(&buf, &i); // Remember that buf knows sizeof(int)
}
printf("Second element (of %d) is %d\n", buf->len, ((int *)buf->array)[1]);
```

Comment: I upvote this because in video game programming we always use void *

Comment: The next step would be to add `void (*free)(void*);` to the struct, a function to free any leftover elements in the array when it's freed

Comment: @ikegami. Only if the elements are pointers to the heap. Freeing the buffer is not element-specific.

Comment: @Mad Physicist Re "*Only if the elements are pointers to the heap.*", One would assign a function that does nothing (or NULL and a check) for those arrays. // Re "*Freeing the buffer is not element-specific*", I didn't mention anything element-specific. I said the next step was adding a single pointer to the array structure.

Comment: @ikegami. I'm not disagreeing with you at all, just saying it's out of scope for this simple example, especially since OP seems mostly interested in primitives. If you want to jump down that rabbit hole far enough, you end up with CPython.

Comment: Re "*OP seems mostly interested in primitives*", I'm assuming you mean primitives other than pointers (cause the feature being discussed is pertinent to pointers). I'm not sure where you got that idea. All they said is that they want it to handle more than "an integer". As far as I'm concerned, it's far more likely to be pointers of some kind. And I have no idea why you think having destructors makes it CPython?

Comment: I tried a solution similar to this one before writing the stack exchange post.  If I change `int *array` to `void *array` within the struct and in the function calls, I get an error every place where I have the code `array-> array[array->len - 1]` that states `Incomplete type void not assignable`.

Comment: @Jon. Correct. Every place you want to use the array, you need to cast it to the type you actually want: `(int *)(array->array)[array->len - 1];`

Comment: Hmmm! I suppose I can instantiate the `Array` struct with an elemeny, lets call it `type`, that represents the different data types and then in an if then statement determine what data type to cast it to.  Is that how you see the solution going in the `int_array` and `append_array`

Comment: @Jon. No. I suggest that you can use these functions to do stuff like memory, but the user is aware of what the type is, not the functions themselves. The functions only care about element size, which you provide in the beginning as `sizeof(int)`, for example.

Comment: @Jon. See the update to my answer

Comment: I dont suppose I could ask you to provide an implementation for `append_int_array`?  When I implement in the way I think you are recommending, I still get an issue when I cast to an int at `(int *)array->array[array->len - 1] = item` that informs me that `Operand of type 'void' where arithmetic or pointer type is required`.  In addition, this would hard code the function for an int which is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: @Jon. Missing parens around the cast. It's done correctly in the answer. Sorry about that

Comment: Which answer?  Five posts above you listed `(int *)(array->array)[array->len - 1] = item`, but that does not work either and produces the same warning.

Comment: @Jon. Correct. That would raise a warning at least. Use `((int *)(array->array))[array->len - 1] = item`

Comment: @MadPhysicist The answer you gave can be made to work, but it does not totally answer my question.  I will vote it as a solution and re-post another more targeted question in the emorning.

Comment: @Jon. I'll be happy to take a look when you do. Glad you got at least something out of it

Comment: @MadPhysicist I just took a new crack at the question here.  The solution I could implement thus far is very close to, but not exactly what you recommended, or at least as far as I understood your solution.  It still gave me casting errors.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71629286/how-to-properly-cast-to-a-void-type-as-an-array-in-c

Answer (score 1):

C is a strongly- and statically-typed language without polymorphism, so in fact no, there is no language-supported form of dynamic typing.  Every object you declare, every function parameter, every struct and union member, every array element has a specific type declared in your source code.

Some of the things you *can* do:

- use a `typedef` or a preprocessor macro to provide indirection of the data type in question.  That would allow you to have (lexically) one structure type and one set of support functions that provide for your dynamically-adjustable array to have any one element type of the user's choice, per program.
- use preprocessor macros to template the structure type and support functions so that users can get separate versions for any and all element types they want.  This might be usefully combined with `_Generic` selection.
- define and use a `union` type for use as the array's element type, allowing use of any of the union's members' types.  With a little more work, this can be made a tagged union, so that objects of different types in the same array could be supported.  The cost, however, is wasted space and worse memory efficiency when you use members having smaller types.
- use `void *` or maybe `uintmax_t` or `unsigned char[some_largish_number]` as the element type, and implement conversions to and from that type.  This has some of the disadvantages of the `union` alternative, plus some complications surrounding the needed conversions.  Also, there is no type that can be guaranteed large enough to accommodate all other data types.  Nor even all built-in data types, though this is a more realistic goal.
- use `void` as the formal element type (possible only with dynamic allocation and pointers, not with an array-style declaration).  Add a separate member that recoirds the actual size of the elements.  Implement wrappers / conversions that support use of that underlying structure in conjunction with various complete data types.  This is described in more detail in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71617822/2402272).