# How to properly cast to a void type as an array

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, types

I am working on a problem in C where I want to create a dynamic growing array, and if possible utilize the same functions for different data types.  Presently I have a struct titled `Array` that uses a void data type titled `*array` which is a pointer to the array.  It also holds `len` which stores the active length of the array, `size` which holds that length of the allocated memory, and `elem` which stores the length of a datatype that is used to dynamically grow the array.

In addition, I am using three functions.  The function `initiate_array` does the heavy lifting of allocating memory for the `array` variable in the struct and instantiating all but one of the struct elements.  The function `init_array` acts as a wrapper around `initiate_array` and also instantiates the variable `elem` in the struct.  Finally, the function `append_array` adds data/indices to the array and reallocates memory if necessary.

At this point the `Array` struct, and the functions `initiate_array` and `init_array` are independent of data type; however, `append_array` is hard coded for `int` variables.  I have tried to make `append_array` somewhat data type independent by making the input `int item` into `void item`, but then I get a compile time error at each location with the code `((int *)array->array)[array->len - 1] = item` that tells me I cannot cast to a void.

My code is below, does anyone have a suggestion on how I can implement the `append_array` function to be independent of the datatype of `item`?

NOTE: I also have a function to free memory at the end of execution, but I am omitting it from this question since it is not relevant.

array.h

```
#ifndef ARRAY_H
#define ARRAY_H

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    void *array;
    size_t len;
    size_t size;
    int elem;
} Array;

void initiate_array(Array *array, size_t num_indices);
Array init_array(int size, size_t num_indices);
void append_array(Array *array, int item);

#endif /* ARRAY_H */
```

array.c

```
#include "array.h"

void initiate_array(Array *array, size_t num_indices) {
    void *pointer;

    pointer = malloc(num_indices * array->elem);

    if (pointer == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to allocate memory, exiting.\n");
        free(pointer);
        exit(0);
    }
    else {
        array->array = pointer;
        array->len = 0;
        array->size = num_indices;
    }
}

Array init_array(int size, size_t num_indices) {
    Array array;
    array.elem = size;
    initiate_array(&array, num_indices);
    return array;
}

void append_array(Array *array, int item) {
    array->len++;
    if (array->len == array->size){
        array->size *= 2;
        void *pointer;
        pointer = realloc(array->array, array->size * array->elem);

        if (pointer == NULL) {
            printf("Unable to reallocate memory, exiting.\n");
            free(pointer);
            exit(0);
        }
        else {
            array->array = pointer;
            ((int *)array->array)[array->len - 1] = item;
        }
    }
    else
        ((int *)array->array)[array->len - 1] = item;
}
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "array.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i, j;
    size_t indices = 20;
    Array pointers = int_array(sizeof(int), indices);

    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        append_int_array(&pointers, i);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < pointers.len; i++)
    {
        printf("Value: %d Size:%zu \n",((int *) pointers.array)[i], pointers.len);
    }

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Yup. I can help with this

Comment: You don't need `pointer` in the first function. `array->array` will work fine directly.

Comment: `append_array` should return a Boolean (int) to indicate success, since memory reallocation can fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by looking at `append_array`. `void` is not a complete type, which means that you can not pass in `void` objects by value. You can pass them by reference though, and `void *` can refer to any other type as well:

```
void append_array(Array *array, void *item) {
```

Right now, you are assuming that you are passing in a single element. But why stop there? You can make your function signature look like this:

```
void append_array(Array *array, void *items, size_t count) {
```

The additional caveat here is that `array->size * 2` may be insufficient to hold the appended data. You could use `(array->len + count) * 2` instead.

Assuming that `array->size` is large enough, you can copy the elements directly using `memcpy` and a cast to `char *`, which is guaranteed by the standard to have size-1 elements:

```
memcpy((char *)array->array + array->len * array->elem, items, count * array->elem);
```

Notice that I used `array->len` for the index here. That is because my next suggestion is to increment `array->len` only after you make the copy. That would make your size check simpler, and not subject to reallocation with one element to spare, as you have now. Remember that `array->len` is not only the size of the array, it is also the zero based index that you want to append to.

```
if (array->len + count > array->size) {
```

For a single element, the condition would be

```
if (array->len >= array->size) {
```

Finally, I strongly suggest you return an integer error code instead of exiting. The user of this function should expect to be able to do cleanup at the very least in case of a memory error, or possibly free up cache elements, not unilaterally crash.

Here is what the final function would look like:

```
int append_array(Array *array, void *items, size_t count)
{
    if (array->len + count > array->size) {
        size_t size = (array->len + count) * 2;
        void *pointer = realloc(array->array, size * array->elem);
        if (pointer == NULL) {
            return 0;
        }
        array->array = pointer;
        array->size = size;
    }
    memcpy((char *)array->array + array->len * array->elem, items, count * array->elem);
    array->len += count;
    return 1;
}
```

Writing the function this way has one slight drawback: since rvalues don't have an address, you can't call

```
append_array(&array, &3, 1);
```

You can work around this in two ways.

1. Make a temporary variable or buffer to hold the value:

   ```
   int tmp = 3;
   append_array(&array, &tmp, 1);
   ```
2. Make a type-specific wrapper that can accept elements for complete types. This works because C is purely pass-by-value (i.e., copy), so you can do

   ```
   int append_int(Array *array, int value)
   {
       return append_array(array, &value, 1);
   }
   ```

   In this case, you are effectively using a new stack frame to hold the value of `tmp` in the first example.

Comment: This as well as many of the other responses have been fantastic and have helped me conceptualize aspects of pointer operations and arithmetic.  However, it appears that the implementation code for this approach with the other functions I plan to write for pop and replace, etc is complex enough to offset the advantages of this approach.  I wonder if I might just be better off drafting a struct for each data type and create a set of init, append, pop, and replace functions for each type and then create an alias function in each struct with the same names to reduce the interface complexities.

Comment: @Jon. Are you asking if replicating dozens of lines of nearly identical code is better than doing a couple of casts and additions? Think of what happens when you discover a bug, typo, or improvement for one of your replicated functions. By the way, most complex functions like pop, push, append, etc. can be written as wrappers for a single generic insert and delete operation.

Comment: I am still contemplating it.  By the time you write all of the wrappers you may have nearly as many functions to maintain, although admittedly, not as many.  To be fair, most of the heavy lifting requiring maintenance would be in just 4 primary functions.

Comment: I might have spoken too soon.  This worked well on integers, but it is not working with float variables.  It compiles correctly and runs, but it is not storing the float variables correctly.

Comment: @Jon. You'd have to show an example. Always room for another good question on SO

Comment: I think I figured this out.  I will likely have more questions soon.

Answer (score 1):

The type `void` is an incomplete type, and one which cannot be completed, so you can't assign to or from it, or use it as an array parameter type.

What you can do is change `append_array` to take a `void *` as an argument which points to the data to be added.  Then you convert your data pointer to `char *` so you can do single byte pointer arithmetic to get to the correct offset, then use `memcpy` to copy in the data.

```
void append_array(Array *array, void *item) {
    array->len++;
    if (array->len == array->size){
        array->size *= 2;
        void *pointer;
        pointer = realloc(array->array, array->size * array->elem);

        if (pointer == NULL) {
            printf("Unable to reallocate memory, exiting.\n");
            free(array->array);
            exit(0);
        }
        else {
            array->array = pointer;
        }
    }
    char *p = (char *)array->array + (array->len - 1) * array->elem;
    memcpy(p, item, array->elem);
}
```

You won't be able to call this function by passing an integer literal to add, but you can use the address of a compound literal.

```
append_array(array, &(int){ 3 });
```

Comment: This is so similar to what I was drafting, I'm not even going to bother posting. Very nice

Comment: One thing: don't call `free(pointer);` inside `if(pointer == NULL)`

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes, that should actually be `free(array->array);` given that `exit` follows.

Comment: Second thing: you need to post-incrememt `array->len`, not pre-increment. I mean it's position in the function, not the `++` operator.

Comment: I wouldn't exit there either. That's really the user's responsibility. Just don't update the existing buffer and return an error code. User may want to do other cleanup. You do need to halve the size in that case though.

Comment: On second thought, I think I'll post an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this, or you could use `typeof` to improve it.
Or, use void **array;

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    void *array;
    size_t size;
    size_t capacity;
    int elem_size;
} Array;

void initiate_array(Array *array, size_t num_indices);
Array init_array(int size, size_t num_indices);
void append_array(Array *array, void *item);

void initiate_array(Array *array, size_t num_indices) {
    void *pointer;

    pointer = malloc(num_indices * array->elem_size);

    if (pointer == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to allocate memory, exiting.\n");
        // free(pointer);
        exit(0);
    } else {
        array->array = pointer;
        array->size = 0;
        array->capacity = num_indices;
    }
}

Array init_array(int elem_size, size_t num_indices) {
    Array array;
    array.elem_size = elem_size;
    initiate_array(&array, num_indices);
    return array;
}

void append_array(Array *array, void *item) {
    if (array->size == array->capacity) {
        // extend the array
    }

    memcpy(array->array + array->size * array->elem_size, item,
           array->elem_size);
    array->size++;
}

int main(void) {
    Array arr = init_array(sizeof(int), 10);

    int item = 1;
    append_array(&arr, &item);
    item = 2;
    append_array(&arr, &item);
    item = 3;
    append_array(&arr, &item);

    return 0;
}
```